# How to send an object with Netty?

Tags: java, javabeans, netty

How to send bean from server side and receive this bean in the client side by Netty?  When I send simple integer message, inputstream, it works successfully but I need to send bean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using netty at client and server side then you can use the Netty [ObjectDecoder](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/serialization/ObjectDecoder.html) and [ObjectEncoder](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/serialization/ObjectEncoder.html) in your `ChannelPipeline` to send and receive objects.

Take a look at the [netty ping pong example](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/NettyExampleOfPingPongUsingObject) which does this. The code is bit out of date, but you will get the general idea on working with objects.